# Integrating the maximum function

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

How can the following expression be calculated:

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \max(0,u_1+u_2-1) du_1du_2 $$

Comment: Just find the subregion of the standard unit square such that
$$u_1 + u_2 \ge 1$$
and revise the limits of integration for the integral over that region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \max(0,u_1+u_2-1)$ is nonzero when $u_1+u_2-1>0$, wich you can write $u_1>1-u_2$.

Then

$$\int_0^1\int_{u_1=1-u_2}^1(u_1+u_2-1)\,du_1\,du_2=\int_0^1\left.\left(\frac{u_1^2}2+u_1u_2-u_1\right)\right|_{1-u_2}^1\,du_2.$$

The rest is yours.

Comment: Thank you, I started with the same approach, but got another result as mathematica. I've checked my computations again and made a sign error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Integration is over a sqaure. $u_1+u_2 \ge 1$ only for the upper-left triangle of the squre, so the lower triangle has integration of $0$